# Maven ignore signature of a dependency package

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, manifest, signature

I have a custom built jar of the Hadoop-azure package under the hadoop project. I need to use this JAR in my project. I imported the JAR as a dependency under Maven using the following configuration.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop.fs.abfs</groupId>
     <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
     <version>2.7.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

However, the when I try to import a signed version of the JAR i encounter the following error.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I see that the signed files from the Manifest could be ignored using the Maven shade plugin. However, these would be ignored from the Uber Jar which shade plugin builds. The structure of tests for this projects is not well done and it is built as a different sub-project under the main project; having its own pom file. When I write integration tests for the classes I intend I keep seeing the java security signature error. Is there a way to ignore the signed files from the Manifest folder other than the shade plugin option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=maven%20add%20third%20party%20jar&oq=maven%20add%20third%20p&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.7871j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to add third party library(in your case hadoop-azure) to your local maven repository then your run your project and should it be well. E.g:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Projects\HadoopAzure\hadoop.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.hadoop.fs.abfs \
    -DartifactId=hadoop-azure -Dversion=2.7.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: curious, how would it help with the issue with signing?